# Display popup confirmation message with MVC C# after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dialog, showmodaldialog

Using MVC Framework with C# coding. The views are written in standard HTML code.
I require a confirmation message saying "Your message has been sent" once the user clicks the submit button

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(ContactViewModel contactVM){
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string url = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath+ "#contact";

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            var contact = new Contact
            {
                Name = contactVM.Name,
                Email = contactVM.Email,
                Subject = contactVM.Subject,
                Message = contactVM.Message
            };
            new Email().Send(contact);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Here is the View:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit_btn left" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" class="submit_btn right" name="Reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `RedirectToAction()`, return `View` :

```
    new Email().Send(contact);

    ViewBag.Message = "Message Sent"; 

    return View();
```

In View:

```
@if(ViewBag.Message != null)
{
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

alert('@ViewBag.Message');

});

</script>

}
```

Comment: or you can override default alert:http://andrewensley.com/2012/07/override-alert-with-jquery-ui-dialog/

Comment: Here have to create one separate view. Or just put the if condition in same view where the submit button present

Comment: @sara in the same view

Answer (score 1):

Add Inside controller

```
        ViewBag.IsEmailSent=true;



public ActionResult Index(ContactViewModel contactVM){
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string url = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath+ "#contact";

                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                var contact = new Contact
                {
                    Name = contactVM.Name,
                    Email = contactVM.Email,
                    Subject = contactVM.Subject,
                    Message = contactVM.Message
                };
                new Email().Send(contact);
                ViewBag.IsEmailSent=true;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Index.cshtml page

```
   @if(ViewBag.IsEmailSent)
    {
    <script>
$(function(){
     $("#successModal").modal('show'); });
    </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the result (from `RedirectToAction("Index")`) to a view that provides the confirmation.

If you don't want to have something that's mostly a copy of an existing page (like `Index`) then pass an object containing a `ShowConfirmation` flag, and in the index view have some logic to show the confirmation if that flag is set.